# Object properties are undefined after localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, undefined, javascript-objects

I'm storing a bunch of values in localStorage. An array with JSON objects in it to be specific. 
When I want to add another object to that array here is how I pull it, parse it, push onto the array and set it again.

```
var clickedItem = sessionStorage.getItem('location'),
interest = [],
interests = localStorage.getItem('interests');
interestsParsed = JSON.parse(interests);
interestsParsed.push(clickedItem);
localStorage.setItem('interests', JSON.stringify(interestsParsed));
```

Later on if I pull the array and loop through the array my properties are undefined.

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('interests'));

for(var i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i++ ){
    console.log(data[i].anything); // any property is undefined
}
```

PS. The JSON object looks completely normal when I console it. Any ideas why the props would be undefined?

**UPDATE:**
data is in fact an array and looping through it does give me each value from within it. However each JSON object in the array is no longer an object and must be JSON.parsed to "recreate" an object out of the string that it is.

**This was a really great lesson on storing JSON objects within an array in localStorage.**

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('interests'));

for(var i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i++ ){
    console.log(data[i].anything); // any property is undefined
    var obj = JSON.parse(data[i]); // parse it instead
    console.log(obj.title); // use it as an object now
}
```

Comment: Is `anything` positively a property and not a method? Because functions will be lost using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Would be easier to help you if you could provide a code example with sample data, using jsfiddle or any alternative.

Comment: @iMoses yessir, nothing is a method, strictly key/val; good to know though. I will put up a fiddle asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is that you are trying to `stringify` a complex object, probably something like a DOM object or another built-in API's object. What happens is that `JSON.stringify` will strip the object out of all methods, and this includes internal setters and getters, and you remain with an empty (or almost empty) object.

My solution in such cases is to parse the complex object into a simple one containing only the properties you need in the formatting of your choosing.

Comment: This was exactly what was happening! Nice explanation thank you for your patient yet informative details which led to an answer. Even though the array values look like objects they are not. Until you json.parse each one in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` returns an `object` but you're treating it as an `array`. Instead of pushing to the array, add a new item to the object.

Comment: Maybe it is the correct solution, but this is incorrect. If `interests` is an array (`"[ ... ]"`) then `JSON.parse` would return an array.

Comment: I agree, but it appears to be an object based on the `for` loop.

Comment: How come? Looks like a classic case of array iteration in JavaScript. If `data` did have a `length` property and/or numerical keys in accordance to `length` then `console.log` would never have been called and and no value (in this case no `undefined`) would be printed to the console.

Comment: Yes exactly. The itteration works exactly as expected with an array. Each place in the "array" is in fact a valid JSON object yet its properties are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage only supports strings. Use JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse().

```
//demo value
var clickedItem = {"testValue":111};
var interests = [{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':4}];
localStorage.setItem('interests', JSON.stringify(interests));
//demo value end
interest = [],
interests = localStorage.getItem('interests');

interestsParsed = JSON.parse(interests);
interestsParsed.push(clickedItem);
console.log(interestsParsed);
localStorage.setItem('interests', JSON.stringify(interestsParsed));

var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('interests'));

for(var i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i++ ){
   console.log(data[i]);
}
```

I think you did't stringify  value  of interests,(before getting value at line no.3)